# Angular JS textarea validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this AngularJS code trying to show two stars next to label when there is no text in the textarea. Same code works for input tags, but not with textarea.

```
<div class="input-left">
    <label for="email">
        <span ng-show="contactform.email.$error.required" class="required">*</span>Email:
    </label>
    <input ng-model="email" type="text" name="email" id="email" required></br></br>
    <label for="budget">Budzet:</label>
    <input ng-model="budget" type="text" name="budget" id="budget">
</div>
<div class="clearboth">
    <label for="msg" class="left" >
        <span ng-show="contactform.msg.$error.required" class="required">**</span>Pitanja ili Komentari?
    </label>
    <textarea ng-model="msg" rows="8" cols="50" class="input-no-width rounded shaded left clearboth" id="msg" required></textarea>
</div>
```

According to [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3atextarea) - textarea should behave same as input.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your problem with the `<textarea>` tag is that it doesn't define `name` attribute.

AngularJS uses the `name` attribute to expose validation errors.

You should define your textarea like so:

```
<textarea ng-model="msg" name="msg" rows="8" cols="50"
          class="input-no-width rounded shaded left clearboth" id="msg" required>
</textarea>
```

Please note that having `id` and `ng-model` is not enough to properly handle validation messages. In AngularJS applications the `id` attribute often doesn't serve much purpose and could be omitted.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking it uses id.

Comment: This helped me a lot. But I think there is something weird going on at the same time. I can leave out the name attribute on a text input field and the validation will work just fine, but the textarea require me to have it there.

Answer (score 0):

For form validation **name** is very important. Give it a name it should work.

```
<textarea ng-model="msg" 
          rows="8" 
          cols="50" 
          class="input-no-width rounded shaded left clearboth" 
          id="msg" 
          name="msg" 
          required>
</textarea>
```